# How do I lock a hard disk drive to a certain drive letter?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an external hard disk drive that I have set to drive F which contains some programs that I have shortcuts on the desktop to. I have a second external hard disk drive which I store my music on which is auto assigned to drive E, due to someone thinking that Australians love to have wings on power plugs for hard drives while power boards have each socket close together. I can have both of these hard drives set at the same time.

My music hard drive I normally only plug in when I synchronise music to my iPod, but on occasion when I unplug my music hard drive and plug my old one back in or at times when I turn on my computer with the music hard disk drive in, turn off my computer and turn it back on with my old hard drive, its drive letter gets switched to E.

I get annoyed having to always go into disk management and change the drive letter back to F when this happens so

- Can I lock my hard drive to always be F? If anything else tries to be F, it can fail for all I care.
- Is there a batch file I can use that'll go though all the steps of Disk Management to change a drive's letter, that way I can set it up in the startup folder?

EDIT:

> **I get annoyed having to always go into disk management and change the drive letter back to F when this happens**

I am just pointing it out in case someone missed it, because I already use Disk Management to change the drive letter back to F. If it stayed there then I would have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use Uwe Sieber's [**USB Drive Letter Manager**](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html). Check out the help file for details on how to configure USBDLM.INI so as to identify a particular drive based on [various criteria](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#by_criteria) and preferentially assign a drive letter to it.